# How do I import photos from my iPhone when using iPhoto in full screen mode on Lion?

Tags: macos, photos.app, import, fullscreen

In non-full screen mode your iPhone shows up in the left side bar under the 'Devices' area. In full screen mode there is no left side bar. I tried `File -> Import to Library...` but there's no iPhone listed in the Finder window that opens up.

How do you import photos from your iPhone when iPhoto is running in full screen mode on Lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iCloud’s [Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) feature. As you noticed, you can’t access an iOS camera device connected via USB from iPhoto in full screen mode (in fact, iPhoto will leave full screen mode when you connect such a device). Photo Stream however is available in full screen mode (in the “All Albums” section). You can even setup iPhoto to automatically import photos from Photo Stream (sorry for the German screenshot, but you’ll get the idea).

[image: Photo Stream import settings in iPhoto (German)]

Comment: The screen shot is showing up, but I got the idea.

Comment: You must have looked at it the moment [CloudApp went down today](http://twitter.com/#!/cloudapp/status/127803007327932416) :). Glad my answer helped nonetheless.